# Django and testing local URLs exist

Tags: django, django-validation

I have a model which needs to store URLs which will be part of the Django environment. If I was storing normal URLs, I'd use [`models.URLField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#urlfield), and use [`verify_exists`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.URLField.verify_exists) to make sure the URL actually exists.

However, this doesn't work that great in development, since the dev server is single-threaded, it hangs indefinitely, since it can't process two requests at once.

I was hoping to do something using [`resolve()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#resolve), but am having difficulty adapting the function `myview` at the end of that documentation page to a version which does not take a request, since I want to check that a given local URL can be resolved, and called without a 404 being raised, from a blank session.

I was hoping to do this with a [validator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/), something like this:

```
def validate_local_url(value):
    try:
        view, args, kwargs = resolve(value)
        view(*args, **kwargs)
    except Resolver404:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a local URL (not a valid URL)' % value)
    except Http404:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a local URL (does not exist)' % value)
```

However, this fails without a valid `request` object being passed into `kwargs`. How do I generate a dummy (blank) request object? I've tried just using `django.http.HttpRequest`.

Comment: How strict do you want to be? Do you want to make it impossible to link to a a missing or deleted record, or do you just want to make sure it matches some view in your application?

Comment: @Jordan - I want to make sure it matches some view, and with the arguments that `resolve` figures out passed to the view, does not raise an `Http404`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild idea, not sure if it will be helpful. Have you considered naming the urls and using [`reverse()`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse)? `Reverse` will work if the URL is valid and will fail when it is not.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd get this to work - users would need to know the names of views and how they get their parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Are you cool with using the [django test Client](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#module-django.test.client)?

If so, this should do it:

```
from django.test.client import Client

def validate_local_url(path):
    c = Client()
    try:
        resp = c.get(path)
        if resp.status_code == 404:
            raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a local URL (does not exist)' % value)
    except:
        raise ValidationError(u'%s is not a local URL (not a valid URL)' % value)
```

Just, you know, make sure under penalty of death that `validate_local_url` can **never** be called by a local `GET` request, otherwise someone can trivially set your server on an infinite loop:

```
# urls.py
url('^infinite_loop/$', 'myapp.infinite_loop', 'infinite_loop')

#views.py
def infinite_loop_view(request, template_name="blah.html", form_class=MyForm):
    my_form = form_class(request.REQUEST or None) # yes, admittedly this is dumb
    if my_form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponse("Congratulations! Your path was totally valid.")
    return render_to_response(template_name, locals(), RequestContext(request))
```

And then:

http://example.com/infinite_loop/?path_field=infinite_loop

Comment: Although I suppose even then it would be okay, since the second call wouldn't send in the path variables, right?

Even so, I would be wary of this decision. Personally, I'd be content with making sure that they created a local URL that points to a valid URL (i.e. doesn't raise Resolver404) and be accepting of the occasional 404.